# Get an empty array when use array of objects in filter function React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and try to get data from the database and view data in frontend. This is the code I tried.

```
function ViewPost() {

    const { postId } = useParams();
    console.log(postId);

    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOnePost();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (post && post.location) {
            console.log(post.location);
            console.log(post.location.longitude);
            console.log(post.location.latitude);
        }
    }, [post]);

    const getOnePost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${postId}`)
            console.log(response);
            const allPost=response.data.onePost;
            setPost(allPost);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(post);

    console.log(post.wasteItemList);

    const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllOffers();
    }, []);

    const getAllOffers = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingOffers;
                setOffers(allNotes);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(offers);

    const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItems => wasteItems.status==='accepted' && wasteItems.wasteItemsListId===post?.wasteItemList?._id);
    console.log(wasteItem);
}
```

When I call the first API I get these results. This is an image of results.

[image: First API call results]

In the above image, there is a length 2 array of objects called as wasteItemList. Then I call the second API and get these results.

[image: Second API call results]

This image shows length 8 array of objects. Then I try to filter the data of these two arrays using this  `const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItems => wasteItems.status === 'accepted' && wasteItems.wasteItemsListId === post?.wasteItemList?._id);` code. But I get a length 0 empty array as the results of this filter function. But when I try an ID of a wasteItemList array
`6112679258125b0418844368` instead of using this `post?.wasteItemList?._id` code I get the correct result. What is the problem here? How do I solve this problem?

Edited code:

```
function ViewPost() {

    const { postId } = useParams();
    const [post, setPost] = useState(undefined);
    const [offers, setOffers] = useState(undefined);
    useEffect(() => {
        setPost(undefined);
        axios
            .get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${postId}`)
            .then((resp) => setPost(resp.data.onePost))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }, [postId]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
            .then((response) => setOffers(response.data.existingOffers))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (post && post.location) {
            console.log(post.location);
            console.log(post.location.longitude);
            console.log(post.location.latitude);
        }
    }, [post]);

    console.log(post);
    console.log(post?.wasteItemList);
    console.log(offers);

    const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItems => wasteItems.status==='accepted' && wasteItems.wasteItemsListId===post?.wasteItemList?._id);
    console.log(wasteItem);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- useEffect runs **asynchronously** so your post will not be available
  on your getAllOffers function which is located in your second
  useEffect.
- You will need to make your **getOnePost()** and **getAllOffers()** to
  run synchronously within a single useEffect.
- Or the problem is in your condition checks as I can't tell much only
  by your given array picture.

Comment: As you mentioned above I remove `async, await` part from the code but then also did not give the correct result. I get an empty array. I added the edited code above.

Comment: No, I meant to put your getOnePost() and getAllOffers() into a single useEffect and make them run one by one. the async, await keywords keep them there since the await keywords make your asynchronous code run synchronously.

Comment: You can imagine like this: All useEffects are executing at the same time so they cannot get value from a cross useEffect. You will need to make your function run one after another.